# Trying to find the database that is used by a Spring/Hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, reverse-engineering

I’ve inherited the thankless task of trying to reverse engineer a particularly convoluted mess of a web application.  More precisely, where said application stores its data.  The original developers have long left for greener pastures, to the point where nobody even remembers who they might have been.

The application apparently uses Spring in tandem with Hibernate.  I managed to find these two data source configuration (in `WEB-INF/spring/datasourceContext.xml`, to be precise):

```
<bean id="oliteTechDataSource" name="oliteTechDataSource"
    class="xxx.yyy.zzz.datasource.tttDataSource" init-method="init">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.lite.poljdbc.POLJDBCDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:polite:</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>MANAGER</value>
    </property>
    <property name="database">
        <value>BIRNBAUM</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

And:

```
<bean id="opeTechDataSource" name="opeTechDataSource"
    class="xxx.yyy.zzz.datasource.uuuDataSource"
    init-method="init">
    <property name="driverClassName">
        <value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</value>
    </property>
    <property name="url">
        <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl11g</value>
    </property>
    <property name="username">
        <value>apfelbaum</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>zypresse</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

These two snippets seem to contradict each other:  The first suggests *Oracle Lite*, the second the ‘full’ Oracle.  I’ve found an instance of the latter running on this machine, namely `Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production` (as reported by SQL*Plus).  The credentials of the second snippet allow me to log in, but other than a few system tables, that database seems empty.  To be precise, the only tables which have non-empty row count when querying `SELECT OWNER, TABLE_NAME, NUM_ROWS FROM ALL_TABLES` are owned by either `SYSTEM` or `SYS`.  My best guest right now is that the data are kept in the database mentioned in the first snippet, but I’ve found no trace of it yet.

The application stops working when deliberately crashing the mentioned Oracle instance, so I assume that the first snippet might be a left-over from some old version that was never removed.  That still leaves me with the question where exactly in that database the data might be hiding.  By logging in with the credentials mentioned above, I get a very small list of tables that are owned by a similar user (let’s call him `apfeladmin`), that’s obviously not an Oracle default user.  All those tables have names of the sort `C$SOMETHING`.  `C$TABLE_LIST` in particular contains names of tables which I have found in queries when disassembling the application.

But where are the actual tables?  I know what Hibernate and Spring are, but not much further.  I only have the compiled classes, together with a bunch of XML files.  Is it possible to discern from those how the data are supposed to be laid out in the database?  How would a ‘typical’ Hibernate-ERP-application do it?  I assume once I know what I am looking for, then I’ll be able to find it.  Or is this ‘just’ a permissions issue, and I won’t be able to get any further until I manage to get DBA access (there’s no-one left who does, so this is not as easy as it should be)?

Comment: _"other than a few system tables, that database seems empty"_ -- how did you determine that?

Comment: I am by no means an expert, but are you sure you have the right privileges to access the database that you want? Some database software hides parts of a database depending on the privileges.

Comment: @PerryMonschau: Your hunch was correct.  Out of desperation I tried to brute force my way into the SYSDBA account and actually managed to.  Et voilà: suddenly all those tables are there.  Care to put it as an answer, so that I can tick it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the right privileges to access the database that you want. Some database software hides parts of a database depending on the privileges.

So trying to access it as Administrator or brute forcing may work. It all depends on the privilege settings given to the database.